# If Statement Returning True for Wrong Statement

Tags: javascript

Wrote a simple little app to check what period it is a display it with Javascript. Works great for the most part - but at certain times it will display the next period instead of the current one.

1. How do I test it without waiting and manually checking?
2. I'd obviously like to figure out why it displays the wrong period

Edit: If the time is 15:06 (3:06PM) it will display the last else statement instead of the second to last one

Code:

```
var now = '';

//Set Periods
//Slot 1+2 are periods - slots 3+4 are passing times inbetween periods
var periods = [
  ['Before School', 5.00, 7.59],
  ['First', 8.00, 8.49, 8.50, 8.54],
  ['Second', 8.55, 9.44, 9.45, 9.49],
  ['Third', 9.50, 10.39, 10.40, 10.44],
  ['Fourth', 10.45, 11.34, 11.35, 11.39],
  ['Fifth', 11.40, 12.29, 12.30, 12.34],
  ['Sixth', 12.35, 13.24, 13.25, 13.29],
  ['Seventh', 13.30, 14.19, 14.20, 14.24],
  ['Eighth', 14.25, 15.15]
];

//Display Period
function displayPeriod() {
  if (now >= periods[0][1] && now <= periods[0][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('School has not started yet');
  } else if (now >= periods[1][1] && now <= periods[1][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('1st');
  } else if (now >= periods[1][3] && now <= periods[1][4]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('1st Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[2][1] && now <= periods[2][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('2nd');
  } else if (now >= periods[2][3] && now <= periods[2][4]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('2nd Passing');
  } else if (now > periods[3][1] && now <= periods[3][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('3rd');
  } else if (now >= periods[3][3] && now <= periods[3][4]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('3rd Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[4][1] && now <= periods[4][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('4th');
  } else if (now >= periods[4][3] && now <= periods[4][4]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('4th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[5][1] && now <= periods[5][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('5th');
  } else if (now >= periods[5][3] && now <= periods[5][4]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('5th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[6][1] && now <= periods[6][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('6th');
  } else if (now >= periods[6][3] && now <= periods[6][4]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('6th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[7][1] && now <= periods[7][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('7th');
  } else if (now >= periods[7][3] && now <= periods[7][4]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('7th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[8][1] && now <= periods[8][2]) {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('8th');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = ('School is done for the day.');
  }
}


//Check Time
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  now = today.getHours() + '.' + today.getMinutes();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);

  displayPeriod();

  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = '0' + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Is `v ar now = ""` a copy/paste error, or is it an error in your actual code?

Comment: copy and paste error

Comment: Can you state the exact time where it displays the wrong period?

Comment: var today = new Date();
 today.setHours(15,02 , 0);

Answer (score 0):

You can test the function by inputting the current time through `startTime()` function. You can comment out the `setTimeout` if you only want to test a specific function. You can check that the output for 15.06 is correct too.

```js
var now = '';

//Set Periods
//Slot 1+2 are periods - slots 3+4 are passing times inbetween periods
var periods = [
  ['Before School', 5.00, 7.59],
  ['First', 8.00, 8.49, 8.50, 8.54],
  ['Second', 8.55, 9.44, 9.45, 9.49],
  ['Third', 9.50, 10.39, 10.40, 10.44],
  ['Fourth', 10.45, 11.34, 11.35, 11.39],
  ['Fifth', 11.40, 12.29, 12.30, 12.34],
  ['Sixth', 12.35, 13.24, 13.25, 13.29],
  ['Seventh', 13.30, 14.19, 14.20, 14.24],
  ['Eighth', 14.25, 15.15]
];

//Display Period
function displayPeriod() {
  console.log(now)
  if (now >= periods[0][1] && now <= periods[0][2]) {
    console.log('School has not started yet');
  } else if (now >= periods[1][1] && now <= periods[1][2]) {
    console.log('1st');
  } else if (now >= periods[1][3] && now <= periods[1][4]) {
    console.log('1st Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[2][1] && now <= periods[2][2]) {
    console.log('2nd');
  } else if (now >= periods[2][3] && now <= periods[2][4]) {
    console.log('2nd Passing');
  } else if (now > periods[3][1] && now <= periods[3][2]) {
    console.log('3rd');
  } else if (now >= periods[3][3] && now <= periods[3][4]) {
    console.log('3rd Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[4][1] && now <= periods[4][2]) {
    console.log('4th');
  } else if (now >= periods[4][3] && now <= periods[4][4]) {
    console.log('4th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[5][1] && now <= periods[5][2]) {
    console.log('5th');
  } else if (now >= periods[5][3] && now <= periods[5][4]) {
    console.log('5th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[6][1] && now <= periods[6][2]) {
    console.log('6th');
  } else if (now >= periods[6][3] && now <= periods[6][4]) {
    console.log('6th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[7][1] && now <= periods[7][2]) {
    console.log('7th');
  } else if (now >= periods[7][3] && now <= periods[7][4]) {
    console.log('7th Passing');
  } else if (now >= periods[8][1] && now <= periods[8][2]) {
    console.log('8th');
  } else {
    console.log('School is done for the day.');
  }
}


//Check Time
function startTime(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = hours != null ? hours : today.getHours(); // use current time if input is empty
    var m = minutes != null ? minutes : today.getMinutes(); // use current time if input is empty
    var s = seconds != null ? seconds : today.getSeconds(); // use current time if input is empty
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    now = h + '.' + m; // move it here to correspond with input

    displayPeriod();

    // var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = '0' + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

startTime();
startTime(15, 6, 0);
```

Comment: This seems to be a suggestion for how to debug the issue, and not an actual answer? If so, this should be turned into a condensed comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Where your problem is:**

Your `startTime` function is setting `now` like this:

```
now = today.getHours() + '.' + today.getMinutes();
```

It's then calculating zero-padded hour and minute values, **but these are not used!**

So, instead of representing nine minutes past eight as `"9.08"`, it is using `"9.8"`.

**How to test your code**

You probably want to learn about unit testing, but that is too big a topic to go over here.

Some of the prinicpals of writing testable code can be applied here, though.

**First**, separate logic from updating UI (or DOM), by refactoring your `DisplayPeriod` function to return a string value instead of modifying the DOM:

```
function displayPeriod() {
  if (now >= periods[0][1] && now <= periods[0][2]) {
    return 'School has not started yet';
  } else if (now >= periods[1][1] && now <= periods[1][2]) {
    return '1st';
  } else if (now >= periods[1][3] && now <= periods[1][4]) {
    return '1st Passing';
  } else if (now >= periods[2][1] && now <= periods[2][2]) {
    return '2nd';

  // (Snip)

  } else {
    return 'School is done for the day.';
  }
}
```

This method would then be used by another method which updates the DOM.

**Second**, allow for injection of dependencies. E.g. You have an implicit dependency on the system clock via the `Date()` constructor. If you refactor `StartTime` to accept a date, then your test code can pass in whichever date values it needs to test different cases:

```
// Note that bugs in this method have not been fixed!
function startTime(today) {
  now = today.getHours() + '.' + today.getMinutes();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);

  // Commented out, as interfers with testing (should be moved to DOM setting method).
  // var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
```

**Third**, use a test framework to run various scenarios and check expected and actual results. Here's a poor man's test case and test execution script:

```
function TestCase(time, expectedResult) {
  startTime(time)
  var result = displayPeriod();
  if (result == expectedResult) {
    console.log("Passed for " + time)
  } else {
    console.log("Failed for " + time + "(" + result + ")");
  }
}

for (minute = 0; minute < 50; minute++) {
  time = new Date(2018, 11, 14, 8, minute);
  TestCase(time, "1st");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check time (add zero in front of numbers < 10) before set now variable

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = checkTime(today.getHours());
  var m = checkTime(today.getMinutes());

  now = h + '.' + m;
  displayPeriod();

  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
```